# Expected parameters in \beamer@makecaption

Tags: beamer, macros, captions

I am trying to understand the semantics of the macro `\beamer@makecaption`in Beamer in order to modify the code in [List of Figures + Beamer? (followup)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/426305/list-of-figures-beamer-followup)

It looks like it expects 4 parameters, where #1 is table or figure, #4 is the optional parameter in `\caption` and #2 and #3 are the main parameter in `\caption` after a bit of adjustment, like adding an ignorespaces or similar command. But what is the difference between #2 and #3 and why could one of them be empty, as the mentioned code suggests.